# SQL Query Springboot with date and operators

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot

Can someone explain me how can i do a request that can return me all data between two dates (not date format, it is a string).

Please do not use prebuilt function. Use a native SQL query that can resolve it in my SpringBoot App.

Actually i have this :

```
@Query(value="SELECT historiquedeploiement.id, namespacename, servicename, tagversion, datedeploiement, datecreationtag, actionby, historiquedeploiement.dateajout FROM categorienamespaces, servicesnamespaces, historiquedeploiement WHERE categorienamespaces.id = historiquedeploiement.idnamespace and servicesnamespaces.id = historiquedeploiement.idservicenamespace and namespacename = ?1 and historiquedeploiement.dateajout >= ?2 and historiquedeploiement.dateajout < ?3", nativeQuery = true)
```

```
ArrayList<HistoriqueDeploiementLecture> findBynamespacenameanddate(String namespacename, String datedebut, String datefin);
```

The problem is .. if datedebut is equal to datefin. No one line will be returned, so how can i do in order to return those lines..

In database the date is like that `2020-04-15T11:56:45Z`.
If i ask to return `2020-04-15T`, i would like that it returns `2020-04-15T11:56:45Z`.

Thanks :)

Comment: _Don't_ store your dates in the database as strings, use proper date or datetime columns.  This will especially cause you trouble with JPA.

Comment: In database it is string or datetime ?

Comment: It's string format.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't think it's possible to put this "2020-04-15T11:56:45Z" as a DATE format in sql..
It's a special format, if no, let me know what the name of this type of date. thanks

Comment: The poblem began on your _database_, when you stored dates as text.  Fix the problem there.

Comment: This date `2020-04-15T11:56:45Z` is stored by RedHat OpenShift.
So on my side, how can i store this date format with mysql ?

Comment: Please check the answer I added below, maybe it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your actual problem likely began when you made the decision on the *database* side to store incoming date information as text, rather than as proper dates.  Once that decision was made, you were then forced to try to do range checks on text dates from Java, which is not ideal.  While it might be able to make it work, it would have been better to insert dates into your MySQL database using `STR_TO_DATE`, e.g.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2020-04-15T11:56:45Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%sZ');
```

This returns a proper date value for the input text.

Comment: Sry but i don't see how to use your thing with spring save : `NewHistorique.setIdnamespace(IdNamespace);
   NewHistorique.setIdservicenamespace(IdService);
   NewHistorique.setTagversion(deploiementrecu.getTagversion());
   NewHistorique.setDatedeploiement(deploiementrecu.getDatedeploiement());
    
                     
  NewHistorique.setDatecreationtag(deploiementrecu.getDatecreationtag());
   NewHistorique.setActionby(deploiementrecu.getActionby());
   historiquedeploiementrepository.save(NewHistorique);`

How can i put your STR_TO.. in it ?